# Need help in identifying bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

I have got a bike as a birthday present. But I can not find it on the official website. So can you help me identify the bike please? I wonder if it is the original Bulls bike or replica. Also wonder which model it is. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Have you asked the person who gave it to you ?  If nothing else you really do need the paperwork for any warranty claim.

Comment: I've also tried posting a link to this question to the Bulls Bikes USA support chat, hopefully they'll have an authorative answer.

Comment: Try a search for bull monster bike rather than fat, I’m sure they exist just not in a position to Google or answer

Comment: I have asked the person who gave me the bike but he does not know anything about the bike. He just bought used bike from third party person.

Answer (score 1):

Based on their website - they don't sell fatbikes.  The two models of full-squish bike are called "wild cup" and "wild one"

https://www.bullsbikesusa.com/wild-cup.html

[image]

But the images show "normal" sized tyres, and distinctively different top-mount for the shock.

So either its a model no-longer sold, it's from a different company with a similar name, or it is a knock-off.

Ask the giver for the paperwork so you can "register the warranty" and do enjoy your new bike.